# Applying pandas merge_asof to entire list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of pandas dataframes all sorted by timestamp, and I want to be able to apply to the pandas merge_asof function to the entire list to merge them all into one. each has a column timestamp and value.

I can't figure out how to loop effectively through the list of dataframes to be able to merge these frames. pd.concat doesnt work since the timestamps are a bit apart so I have to use merge_asof, but it doesnt seem like I can apply this function to more than 2 dataframes at a time. I am unsure how I can apply this function to an entire list to get one final merged frame

Comment: It's not clear to me what you want exactly. If you want to concatenate a list of dataframes that have the same columns then just use `pd.concat`—plenty of examples in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html). Are you trying to merge all the dataframes on the nearest timestamp of one of the dataframes? Because that's what [`pd.merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) is for.

Comment: @russhoppa I am trying to merge the dataframes on the nearest timestamp, but I cannot figure out how to do so with an entire list of dataframes as pd.merge_asof only works for 2 dataframes at a time

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you're trying to merge a list of dataframes on the nearest timestamp using `pd.merge_asof`.

Try this using `for` loop:

```py
def merge_dataframes(df_list):
    # Start with the first dataframe in the list
    merged_df = df_list[0]
    
    # Iteratively merge dataframes in the list
    for df in df_list[1:]:
        merged_df = pd.merge_asof(merged_df, df, on='timestamp')

    return merged_df
```

or using `reduce`:

```py
from functools import reduce

def merge_two_dfs(df1, df2):
    return pd.merge_asof(df1, df2, on='timestamp')

def merge_dataframes(df_list):
    return reduce(merge_two_dfs, df_list)
```

Use:

```py
dfs = [df1, df2, df3, ...]  # List of your dataframes
result = merge_dataframes(dfs)
```

Note 1: Make sure all your dataframes are sorted by the timestamp column before using these functions, as `merge_asof` requires the 'on' key (in this case, 'timestamp') to be sorted.

Note 2: If your dataframes have other overlapping columns besides "timestamp", you might need to specify additional arguments in the `merge_asof` function to handle `suffixes` or to specify which columns to merge on. Adjust the merge function accordingly based on your specific requirements.